# Creating multiple different lines in live graph

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

Im newbie in python and I want to create live graphs for analysis my data.I will take my data from my local file and I need to create multiple lines for each data.

So I want to see multiple lines on graph

Sample local data(for one line):

```
1,4
2,5
3,7
4,9
5,2
6,8
7,1
8,3
9,10
10,4
```

Code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
from matplotlib import style

import numpy as np
import urllib
import datetime as dt


style.use('fivethirtyeight')

fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)



def animate(i):
    graph_data=open('api2.txt','r').read()
    lines = graph_data.split('\n')
    xs = []
    ys = []
    for line in lines:
        if len(line) > 1:
            x, y = line.split(',')
            xs.append(x)
            ys.append(y)
        ax1.clear()
        ax1.plot(xs, ys)

ax1.plot([],[],linewidth=5, label='loss', color='r', alpha=0.5)


ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, interval=1000)
plt.show()
```

[sample output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/udJ0y.png)

Desire to use my original data sample(multiple line goes like that):

```
142.5,423.0,225.2,423.5,942.1,541.5
518.6,234.1,115.9,163.5,412.0,234.8
123.4,144.6,435.8,341.1,623.8,423.1
454.2,734.4,645.7,633.7,412.5,991.3
441.4,414.1,413.6,912.1,674.3,233.6
712.2,242.4,865.5,523.9,122.2,133.4
142.5,423.0,225.2,423.5,942.1,541.5
518.6,234.1,115.9,163.5,412.0,234.8
123.4,144.6,435.8,341.1,623.8,423.1
454.2,734.4,645.7,633.7,412.5,991.3
441.4,414.1,413.6,912.1,674.3,233.6
712.2,242.4,865.5,523.9,122.2,133.4
```

Comment: At which point do you have problems? What exactly should be animated here?

Comment: I created live graph with single line.But now I want to create multiple lines using with last data sample set.